# Why Not Least Quartic Instead of Least Squares?

Tags: optimization, least-squares

We are currently using **Least Squares** to calculate the error:
$$\min_{a,b}\sum_{k=1}^n(ax_k+b-y_k)^2$$

Last squares magnifies the error making it bigger for larger errors, and this magnification becomes sort of "leverage" to correct the error faster for iterative methods (like Levenberg-Marquard for example).

But why don't we magnify the error more, and use **Least Quartic** errors?

$$\min_{a,b}\sum_{k=1}^n(ax_k+b-y_k)^4$$

Would this make iterative methods like Levenberg-Marquard more efficient and lead to fewer iterations?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you mean least *quartic*?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, sorry for the typo, yes, I mean _quartic_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the main motivation comes form what we know to solve well.
We mostly know how to solve Linear problems.

Linear Least Squares have 2 great properties:

1. It is Convex. Namely once we found a solution it is *the solution*.
2. Its derivative is linear which is a problem we know how to solve.

Your *Least Quartic* method doesn't satisfy having linear derivative which means we are left with hard problem to solve.

Specifically about *Making the Error Large*, it is not a good property as it means the method is very sensitive to outliers. See Robust Regression in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add another reason to the list of @Royi.

If we assume that the errors follow a normal distribution and are also independently and identically distributed, we can derive the least squares solution as the Maximum Likelihood solution.

See also the following [quote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#Least_squares.2C_regression_analysis_and_statistics) from Wikipedia.

> When the observations come from an exponential family and mild conditions are satisfied, least-squares estimates and maximum-likelihood estimates are identical.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#Least_squares.2C_regression_analysis_and_statistics) The method of least squares can also be derived as a method of moments estimator.